# Google Play Music Icon Is Incorrect

Tags: google-play-music

I was adding songs into my Google Play Music on my Nexus 5X and noticed something: The song icon is incorrect. Look at the following picture:

[image: descr]

As you can see, I imported the song "Faded", but the icon is the cover of another song<sup>#</sup>, which is incorrect.

<sup>#</sup> The icon is correct on my Win7

***Note: Here's what I've done so far***

- Rebooted my Nexus 5X
- Re-downloaded the music for serval times
- Cleared the Google Play Music cache
- Cleared the Google Play Music data

Please help me fix this issue, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, although superficial, solution would be to manually change the cover cover image (download it using a web browser and set it as the album cover). The following link has instructions on how to edit metadata and album art.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1100174?hl=en

If the problem persists with other songs in the future, you could try using a file managing app to solve the issue by searching for and deleting the image you are seeing (might be a leftover thumbnail somewhere or in the Google Play Music folder).

Comment: When I change this incorrect song's icon, the others songs' icon also changes....